# What do you make of these ingredients in Ice Cream?

Tags: dessert, ice-cream

konjac flour, as well as guar gum, vegetable glycerin, carrageenan gum, and locust-bean gum.

What type of ice cream would this make?

Comment: Are you asking what each one of them are responsible for, or the general purpose of these ingredients?

Comment: I am asking, if I was to combine them, what would I get, what type of ice cream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Konjac and Guar Gum will contribute to an elastic and stretchy texture. Glycerin flakes, locust bean gum and carrageenan will act as a stabilizer for the ice-cream, preventing large ice crystal formation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I was to only use for example just Konjac and locust bean gum, would it be enough for it to be stretchy and elastic?

Comment: If you’re following a custard based ice-cream recipe, only Konjac should be enough to get that effect.

Answer (score 1):

When using your ingredients and "ice cream" in a search Duck Duck Go finds "[Dondurma Is the Chewy, Stretchy Ice Cream You Need to Know About](http://www.grubstreet.com/2017/08/dondurma-chewy-ice-cream.html)", which does have all of the ingredients you list.

Answer (score 1):

No type of "Ice cream" by definition.

Some sort of "Frozen non-dairy dessert", perhaps, but not if those are the only ingredients, IMHO.